# Convert *text* into <span>text</span> with function

Tags: php

How can I take a string like this: `*Up to* $1,000`

and turn it into this: `<span>Up to</span> $1,000`

The stars can be anywhere in the string and also there can be multiple sets of stars.  But each set should replaced with span's.

e.g.

`text *test* here` = `text <span>test</span> here`

`text here *test* right *now*` = `text here <span>test</span> right <span>now</span>`

I need to be able to pass the value into a function and receive the formatted string in return.  Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Thanks!  I couldn't find that other question for the life of me!  I looked for a good half hour before asking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple regex can do this:

```
function replace_star($str) {
    return preg_replace('~\*([^*]*)\*~ms', '<span>\1</span>', $str);
}

echo replace_star('*Up to* $1,000') . "\n";
echo replace_star('text here *test* right *now*');
```

Output:

```
<span>Up to</span> $1,000
text here <span>test</span> right <span>now</span>
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed!!! Thank you so much!!!